# jQuery filtering and toggling for searching

Tags: jquery, filter, toggle

I have multiple chatlog as a contact card and I have a search box for searching their contact number. For my searchbox I use `onKeydown` to do the searching like whatsapp searching for contact with number.
But my searching does not work as expected, the searching will either showing all or hiding all of my chatlog.

How can I search for a number and display the correct chatlog.

```
<div class="contactlist-container">

    <div id="chatlog" value="0105653762">
        <div class="chatlog-avatar">
            <img src="res/images/user-avatar.png" style="height: 40px; width: 40px;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="chatlog-contact">
            <div id="chatlog-contactnumber">
                <span>
                    010-565 3762
                </span>
            </div>
            <div id="chatlog-lastchat">
                <span>
                    Hello there
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="chatlog" value="010777777">
        <div class="chatlog-avatar">
            <img src="res/images/user-avatar.png" style="height: 40px; width: 40px;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="chatlog-contact">
            <div id="chatlog-contactnumber">
                <span>
                    010-777 7777
                </span>
            </div>
            <div id="chatlog-lastchat">
                <span>
                    Hello there, Welcome to our customer service system.
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="chatlog" value="010888888">
        <div class="chatlog-avatar">
            <img src="res/images/user-avatar.png" style="height: 40px; width: 40px;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="chatlog-contact">
            <div id="chatlog-contactnumber">
                <span>
                    010-888 8888
                </span>
            </div>
            <div id="chatlog-lastchat">
                <span>
                    Welcome, my name is Kinabalu
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.search-container input#chatsearch').on("keyup", function(){
    var number = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#chatlog #chatlog-contactnumber span').filter(function(){
        $('.contactlist-container #chatlog').toggle($('#chatlog-contactnumber span')
            .text().toLowerCase().indexOf(number) >  -1);
    });
    //
    //  Something gonna edit here, cant target current chatlog
    //
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this
You made some mistakes in your HTML please check the below code.

```
<div class="contactlist-container" id="chatlog_container">
  <div class="chatlog" value="0105653762">
    <div class="chatlog-avatar">
      <img src="res/images/user-avatar.png" style="height: 40px; width: 40px;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="chatlog-contact">
      <div class="chatlog-contactnumber">
        <span>010-565 3762</span>
      </div>
      <div id="chatlog-lastchat">
        <span>Hello there</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="chatlog" value="010777777">
    <div class="chatlog-avatar">
      <img src="res/images/user-avatar.png" style="height: 40px; width: 40px;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="chatlog-contact">
      <div class="chatlog-contactnumber">
        <span>010-777 7777</span>
      </div>
      <div id="chatlog-lastchat">
        <span>Hello there, Welcome to our customer service system.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class ="chatlog" value="010888888">
    <div class="chatlog-avatar">
      <img src="res/images/user-avatar.png" style="height: 40px; width: 40px;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="chatlog-contact">
      <div class="chatlog-contactnumber">
        <span>010-888 8888</span>
      </div>
      <div id="chatlog-lastchat">
        <span>Welcome, my name is Kinabalu</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery function

```
$('.search-container input#chatsearch').on("keyup", function(){
    var number = $(this).val();
    $('#chatlog_container .chatlog .chatlog-contact .chatlog-contactnumber span').filter(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().toggle($(this).text().indexOf(number) > -1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks it is working but what is my mistake on HTML? Can you please explain ?

Comment: You used #chatlog id multiple times, one id can be used once per page. the class can be used multiple times.
please read the below documentation.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp

Comment: thanks so the `chatlog-lastchat` from your HTML will be need to change to class instead of id?

Comment: Yes, please review my code you will get a better idea.